# Перенос запроса SQL через RestApi

Tags: java, sql, json, rest

Новичок. Есть Entity з полями id, date, amount, currency, product (Типа контроль своих расходов - дата покупки, сума, валюта и продукт). Мне нужно, чтоб в ендпойнте групировалось по отсортированной дате. То есть, получить JSon  типа

```
“2021-04-27”: [
{
“2021-04-22”: [
{
“id”: 2,
“date”: “2021-04-22”,
“amount”: 12,
“currency”: “USD”,
“product”: “Salmon”
}
],
“2021-04-27”: [
{
“id”: 4,
“date”: “2021-04-27”,
“amount”: 4.75,
“currency”: “EUR”,
“product”: “Beer”
}
```

Пробую делать через Sql запрос -

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG( date, grp ) AS json FROM ( SELECT date, JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT( "product", product, "id", id ) ) AS grp FROM expense GROUP BY date ) AS tmp 
ORDER BY date
```

. Через аннотацию Querry все время выбивает ошибку, что ip отсутствует. Подскажите пожалуйста (только примером кода), как реализовать этот запрос (через `DAO`, `RestService`, `RestService` и `RestController`? Ниже Entity.

```
 - @Entity
public class Expense {

    

    @Id
        @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;    
        private LocalDate date;
        private Double amount;
        private String currency;
        private String product;
```

Таблица SQL:

```
use expenses
```

create table expenses
( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DATE date ,
AMOUNT DOUBLE,
CURENCY DOUBLE,
PRODUCT varchar (45) )

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO expense(date, amount, currency, product) 
VALUES 
('2021-04-22', 12, 'USD', 'Salmon'), 
('2021-04-27', 4.75, 'EUR', 'beer')
```

Результат:

Результат:

localhost:8080/expenses

```
"2021-04-22": 
   [ { "id": 2, "date": "2021-04-22", 
"amount": 12, 
"currency": "USD", 
"product": "Salmon" }],
 "2021-04-27": 
   [ { "id": 4, 
   "date": "2021-04-27", "amount": 4.75, 
  "currency": "EUR", 
   "product": "Beer" }
```

Comment: Create:
use expenses

create table expenses(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DATE date(20),
AMOUNT DOUBLE(20),
CURENCY DOUBLE(20),
PRODUCT varchar (45)
)

Insert:


INSERT INTO expenses(date, amount, currency, product)
VALUES
('2021-04-22', 12, 'USD', 'Salmon'),
('2021-04-27', 4.75, 'EUR', 'beer')
Результат:
http://localhost:8080/expenses
"2021-04-22": [
 {
 "id": 2,
 "date": "2021-04-22",
 "amount": 12,
 "currency": "USD",
 "product": "Salmon"
 }],
 "2021-04-27": [
 {
 "id": 4,
 "date": "2021-04-27",
 "amount": 4.75,
 "currency": "EUR",
 "product": "Beer"
 }

Comment: несколько секунд, все будет

Comment: Готово , вопрос откорректирован

Comment: Ок. А теперь просветите - для какого сервера БД этот код? Для всех распространённых СУБД (MS SQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, MySQL/MariaDB, SQLite, Interbase/Firebird) он синтаксически ошибочен.

Comment: Виправив - була помилка в запиті

Comment: И опять - для какого сервера БД этот SQL-код?

Comment: MySql база данних.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECTAGG(`date`, JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 
                                                     'date', `date`, 
                                                     'amount', amount,
                                                     'currency', currency,
                                                     'product', product))) result
FROM expenses
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50254f3c4a0a96ce75aa09a7e11afa6a

Comment: Спасибо, возможно, я не четко вопрос задал - мне верно прописать етот запрос в классе Java (RestApi - в RestController, в Service или  Интерфейс Repository ) - чоб на виходе получить в браузер или PostMan етот JSON, которий получился в результате запроса БД

Comment: Вот насчёт "как в Java" - понятия не имею. Ибо не использую. Но как raw SQL через коннектор обязано работать. А поскольку параметры в запросе отсутствуют - то почему нет?